# MySQL Subquery Repetition Avoidance in WHERE/AND

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, reusability

I have a SQL query, where I'm using a subquery in a WHERE clause. I then need to use the same subquery again to compare it to a different column.

I'm assuming there isn't a way for my to access 'emp_education_list li' outside of the subquery?

I'm guessing the subquery repetition is redundant. I'm a bit rusty in SQL to be frank though.

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname
    FROM employee e, emp_education_list l
    WHERE
        e.skillsID = l.skillsID
    AND
    (
        SELECT li.educationID
            FROM emp_education_list li, job j
            WHERE j.skillsID = li.skillsID
            AND j.jobID = 1001
    ) = l.educationID
    AND
    (
        SELECT li.edu_level
            FROM emp_education_list li, job j
            WHERE j.skillsID = li.skillsID
            AND j.jobID = 1001
    ) < l.edu_level
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
SELECT  e.fname, e.lname
FROM    employee e 
        INNER JOIN emp_education_list l
            ON e.skillsID = l.skillsID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  li.educationID, li.edu_level
            FROM    emp_education_list li
                    INNER JOIN job j 
                        ON j.skillsID = li.skillsID
            WHERE   j.jobID = 1001
        ) x ON  l.educationID = x.educationID
WHERE   x.edu_level < l.edu_level
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with `JOIN`  i guess proper joining will take care of rest of the conditions

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname
FROM employee e 
JOIN  emp_education_list l ON (e.skillsID = l.skillsID)
JOIN job j  ON ( j.skillsID = l.skillsID AND j.jobID = 1001)
```

Comment: returns results different from my current statement. Your query returns an empty set, whereas mine returns one row.

Comment: Can you add the fiddle example with your dataset

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname
FROM employee e, 
     emp_education_list l,
     job j
WHERE
         e.skillsID = l.skillsID
     and j.skillsID = l.skillsID
     and j.jobID = 1001
```

Comment: returns results different from my current statement. Your query returns an empty set, whereas mine returns one row.

Comment: If query returns emty set, You should use 'JOIN'. It difficult to understand how you store your data in tables.